# Text-decoration not applied on disabled option from select

Tags: css, html-select, text-decorations

I'm trying to apply custom css on a disabled option from a select tag :

```
  form select option[disabled] {
      color: #999;
      text-decoration: line-through;
  }
```

And only the "color" property is applied, any ideas why the "text-decoration" is not taking into account ?

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847993/text-decoration-line-through-not-working-on-ie) seems related.

Comment: Seems to work for me http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/7XHFy/ (Firefox)

Comment: Thanks Harry, indeed it doesn't work with Chrome and IE.