# Line-through css styling for Option in Select Box is not working on Google Chrome but working fine on Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I added the `!important` tag to the line-through styling in Google Chrome but it didn’t seem to work. Is there a solution or a work around that could solve this issue?

Comment: Can you please explain? I did not understand you.

Comment: Please provide code and make the question more clear

Comment: Code is needed so that we know what you're asking.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/gLqh9/

Answer (score 2):

The `<del>` tag carries the *line-through* or *strike-through* styling by default, and you may use it directly to strike-through the text in your markup.

The following CSS should be used to give a separate element the line-through styles (eg. `<span>`, `<div>` etc.):

```
.line-through {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

And in the markup, you may use the above defined CSS as:

<span class="line-through">Deleted text</span>

The above mentioned examples work seamlessly on every browser without adding an *!important* with the styles. Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ssur/) for a quick demo. Please share your code if possible, would be helpful to figure out the actual problem.

Comment: But this is not working for the `option` tag inside the `select` box

Comment: this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/gLqh9/) has the exact same code that I am using.

Comment: Hey AlGallaf! Kindly refer to [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12848646/2854304) with similar problem with the `<select>` tag and `line-through` style. I think that's exactly what I want to say in this case.

Comment: Adding a `disabled` attribute to the `<option>` tag would do the trick. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gLqh9/4/)

Comment: The option is disable but the line-thought styling is not showing.